# Duvida em criação de Tabela

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Boa Noite,
Estou criando um banco de dados para uma associação, onde é necessário fazer a renovação todo semestre.
Criei uma table de cadastrado com os dados dos sócios:

```
create table Cadastrados(
Nome varchar(50),
Matricula varchar(9) unique,
primary key (Matricula),
)default charset = utf8;
```

Inserindo dados na tabela Cadastrados:

```
insert into Cadastrados values
('Julio', '13.2.7777'),
('Mila', '14.2.5555'),
('Carlos Junior', '12.1.1010');
```

Até ai tudo bem, meu "problema" começa agora:

```
create table Socio_Periodo_16_1 (
Matricula_Cadastrado varchar(9) not null,
Socio_16_1 tinyint(1) not null,
foreign key (Matricula_Cadastrado) references Cadastrados (Matricula)
)default charset = utf8;

insert into socio_periodo_16_1 values
('13.2.7777', '1'),
('14.2.5555', '1'),
('12.1.1010', '0');
```

16_1 significa 1º semestre de 2016. O tinyint 1 significa que o cadastrado renovou no período em questão. E o tinyint 0, significa que não renovou.

Eu devo acompanhar se o cadastrado tem renovado ou não por vários períodos (16.1, 16.2, 17.1, 17.2, 18.1, 18.2...). O jeito que achei foi criando vários tabelas `Socio_Periodo_16_2`, `Socio_Periodo_17_1`, `Socio_Periodo_17_2` e etc...E fazendo um select do tipo:

```
select cadastrados.Nome, cadastrados.Matricula, socio_periodo_16_1.Socio_16_1, socio_periodo_16_2.Socio_16_2, socio_periodo_17_1.Socio_17_1
from cadastrados
inner join socio_periodo_16_1 on socio_periodo_16_1.Matricula_Cadastrado = cadastrados.Matricula
inner join socio_periodo_16_2 on socio_periodo_16_2.Matricula_Cadastrado = cadastrados.Matricula
inner join socio_periodo_17_1 on socio_periodo_17_1.Matricula_Cadastrado = cadastrados.Matricula
order by Nome;
```

O código rodou tranquilamente, mas sei lá...estou achando muito "porco" criar 1 tabela por período. Meu conhecimentos em SQL acabam por aqui, pois comecei a estudar por conta tem umas 2 semanas.

Então venho aqui perguntar, existe alguma coisa mais pratica que eu possa fazer para otimizar esse código?

Desde já agradeço

Answer (score 0):

Minha sugestão é que você faça um relacionamento **MUITOS-PARA-MUITOS**. (Segue um exemplo conceitual. Atenção no `**SociosPeriodo**`

Conceitualmente falando você precisa criar:

```
create table Cadastrados(
Nome varchar(50),
Matricula varchar(9) unique,
primary key (Matricula),
)default charset = utf8;

create table Periodo(
Nome varchar(50),
Id int unique,
primary key (Id),
)default charset = utf8;

create table SociosPeriodo (
Matricula varchar(9) not null,
PeriodoId int not null,
foreign key (Matricula) references Cadastrados (Matricula)
foreign key (PeriodoId) references Periodo (Id)
)default charset = utf8;
```

Depois para consultar isso, você terá muito mais facilidade. Por exemplo:

```
Select * from Cadastrados C
Inner Join SociosPeriodo S on S.Matricula = C.Matricula
Inner Join Periodo P on S.PeriodoId = P.Id
Where P.nome = 'NomeSeuPeriodo'
```